# How to add Office Interops from Office 2007 while using Office 2016

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio-2008, interop, office-2007

In our firm we use a self-writen tool, created with Visual Studio 2008. Most of my colleagues are still using Office 2007 and Windows 7, but I use Office 2016 and Windows 10.

Our tool has interaction with Office, such as creating e-mails or excel files. For this, we use the COM-references Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

After I migrated to Office 2016 (Office 365), Visual Studio is unable to find the references to Office. This means, I can't choose them from the COM-references, because they are missing in the list, for example Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library: [(See picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3YxH.png). 
The problem occured, after I deinstalled the old Office 2007.

To be accurate: After I deinstalled Office 2007, my references changed to [Version 16 (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GCQF.jpg) instead of 12, what they were [before (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUPsJ.jpg). But with Version 16, the interaction with Office (respective Outlook, Excel and Word) does not work. When I remove the references, I can't add them again.

After some research I tried to install the [Primary Interop Assemblys](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18346) from the Microsoft website, but it doesn't change anything. The Object Libraries for Word, Excel and Outlook still don't appear in the list (see the first picture I added).

In another article (don't remeber which) I read about NuGet, and that you can install the assemblys with it, but also read, that NuGet is not available for VS 2008.

I can't add the needed Interops, so my tool doesn't work anymore and I can't find a solution, how to add the Office 2007 references without installing Office 2007 again.

I hope somebody has an idea and thanks ahead!